# form submits on formvalidation false

Tags: javascript

am confused why my form still submits despite my formvalidation function returns false. Below are my codes and i barely can figure out what i did wrong. Please help guys

here is my form script

```
<form name="regForm" action= "/upload.php" method="post" enctype= "multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<p><span class="error" id="reportErr"></span></p>
<label>Do you have an Agent?</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="agent" value="YES"><label>YES</label><input type="radio" name="agent" value="NO"><label>NO</label
<label>Are you under a contract</label><input type="radio" name="contract" value="YES"><label>YES</label><input type="radio" name="contract" value="NO"><label>NO</label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Preview" <input type="reset"  value="Clear">
```

javascript function goes thus:

```
function validateForm(){

var formvalid= true;//even when i set to be false it still submits form

//check for agent user selection


var agent = document.forms["regForm"]["agent"].value;


if (agent == "") {
    document.getElementbyId("reportErr").innerHTML = "Select if you have an agent or not";
    formvalid=false;
}else{

      if (agent =="YES"){
        //handle user input for agentname

         }
       }


      }
//check for contract user selection
var contract = document.forms["regForm"]["contract"].value;
if (contract==""){
   document.getElementbyId("reportErr").innerHTML = "Select if under contract or not";
   formvalid = false;
}else{

      if (contract =="YES"){
        //handle user input for contractname

         }
       }
if (formvalid==false){
return false;

  }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? I think you'll find you have a syntax error, one to many `}`. Some consistent code formatting can help you spot these issues. See : http://jsfiddle.net/k7g5swc8/2/, note my comment with the extra `}`

Comment: On a side note, your validate method should always explicitly return a value. Your final statement in the method should read something like `return formvalid `

Comment: @JonP i tried that  but that still did not work

Comment: i tried rewriting the if function and even had it streamlined to a single if condition , yet my form stil submits on return false.

Comment: Let's double check with `function validateForm(){ return false;}` This will then let us know if the problem is within the function or somewhere else. Did you double check for any other console errors?

Answer (score 0):

yea i figure out what i did wrong 
 document.getElementbyId("reportErr").innerHTML //wrong and was posting my form.
it should be 
document.getElementById().innerHTML. 
tnx JonP for your concern. ur clue helped me work through this task